# Nilpotent group such that $G$/$G'$ is cyclic or a Prüfer group

Tags: group-theory

I've been trying to solve these questions with no luck.

> Let $G$ be nilpotent group such that $G$/$G'$ is cyclic or a Prüfer group. I want to show that $G$ is abelian. Is it true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does this question come from? What is the motivation?

Comment: Here the context is very important. What have you tried and what do you know?

Comment: The answer to the question is yes, it is true.

Comment: @DerekHolt Any Hint because i can't see it

Comment: Try working modulo $[[G,G],G]$.

Comment: @tomaz you can read Newman and Wiegold paper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case $G/[G,G]$ is cyclic.

Write $G=G^0, G^1=[G,G], G^{n+1}=[G,G^n]$.

Proof recurrence on $n$ such that $G^n=1$.

$n=0$ done.

Suppose the result true for $n$ and $G$ a nilpotent group such that $G^{n+1}=1$. Then $G^n$ is contained in the center $Z(G)$ of $G$, remark that $G/G^{n}$ verify the property, thus $G/G^{n}$ is commutative.

Lemma $[G,G]\subset Z(G)$ if $G/G^n$ is commutative.
Let $x,y\in G$, $p:G\rightarrow G/G^n$ $p([x,y])=[p(x),p(y)]=1$, thus $[x,y]\in G^n\subset Z(G)$

Proof continue

Let $x$ in $G$ such that the image of $x$ by $p:G\rightarrow G/[G,G]$ is a generator, for every $y,z \in G$, $y=x^lu, z=x^mu', u,u'\in [G,G]$, $y$ and $z$ commute. since $[G,G]\subset Z(G)$done.